# C++ Overtime / Payroll / Time and a half/ Double Time

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i know my if statement is not correct somewhere but i do not know where? or maybe its just the logical error?

After 8 hours any hours worked will be paid time and a half. That is, given the wage per hour multiply by 1.5. That wage is paid for hours after 8 hours.

After 10 hours any hours worked will be paid double time. That is, given the wage per hour multiply by 2.0. That wage is paid for hours after 10 hours.
Please show: ( Example output )

Wage per hour: 12.37
Hours worked : 10.3

Pay for ( 0 to 8 hours) :            98.96

Pay for hours 8 to 10) :            37.11

Pay for hours (10 and beyond): 7.42

Total Gross Pay :                   143.49

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double HoursWorked;
double WagePerHour;
double TotalWages;
double TimeAndHalf;
double Overtime;
char ContinueChar;

//test cases: 10.5 hours @ 12/hour = $96.00, 2 hours at 1.5 rate = $36.00, .5 hour at 2.0 rate = $12.00
// 6.3 hours @ 12/hour = 75.6, no hours of overtime or double time
//12.5 hours @ 14.34/ hour = $114.72, 2 hours at 1.5 rate = 43.02, 2.5 hours at 2.0 rate = $71.70
//3.7 hours @ 19/hour = $70.30
// 14 hours @ 23.50/hour = $188, 2 hours at 1.5 rate = $70.50, 4 hours at 2.0 rate = $188
//I tested with test test cases and the program had the same results.

int main()
{

    cout << "Ticket #64220\n";
    cout << "CMPR-120\n";
    cout << "Instructor : Joel Kirscher\n";
    cout << "Student: Seyed Shariat\n";
    cout << "Payroll Overtime";
    cout << "\n\n";



    do {
        cout << "How many hours did you work this pay period: \n";
        cin >> HoursWorked;
        cout << "What wage do you get paid per hour?: \n";
        cin >> WagePerHour;
        cout << "So you your paycheck will be: " << HoursWorked * WagePerHour << " before taxes are taken out. \n";

        if (HoursWorked > 8 && <= 10)
            cout << "For the hours you worked over 8, and less than or equal to 10 you made: " << HoursWorked * 1.5 * WagePerHour << " \n";
        else (HoursWorked >10);
        cout << "For the hours you worked over 10: " << HoursWorked * 2.0 * WagePerHour << " \n";

        cout << "Do you want this to run again? (y=Yes): ";
        cin >> ContinueChar;
    } while (ContinueChar == 'y' || ContinueChar == 'Y');


    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***i know my if statement is not correct somewhere but i do not know where? or maybe its just the logical error?*** This is what a debugger is for. Since this is tagged Visual c++ you have access to a good debugger that will let you single step through the code looking at the variables at each step to see where your code appears to execute differently from your expectations.

Comment: `if (HoursWorked > 8 && <= 10)` does not do what you want. You need to have `HoursWorked` compare to the <= 10 part. I mean use `if (HoursWorked > 8 &&  HoursWorked  <= 10)` instead of `if (HoursWorked > 8 && <= 10)`. I am surprised that the compiler did not at least warn about this. I get an error here: https://ideone.com/ijej0C that is very specific.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you!

i totally forgot to add the HoursWorked  before the <= 10...

Comment: so that handles one aspect...now it compares correctly but still i am not getting the right code.

Comment: for example

how many hours did you work this pay period:
8
what wage do you get paid per hour?
15
paycheck should be 120 before taxes but then it starts to computer the 8 - 10 as well as the hours over 10. so it outputs 180 and 240 as well. 

anyone have teamviewer?

Comment: The example output gives you a great clue as to how to approach the solution. It first considers the first eight hours, then the next two, then any amount over 10, and adds up the three to get a total. Your approach seems to be trying to pick one of three different courses depending on the total hours worked. I suggest that it's easier to think of this, not as "one of A or B or C applies to this case" but as "A may apply, and if so, B may also apply, and if so, C may also apply"

Comment: @TimRandall right, i undertand what you are trying to explain, i think.

so what would my code look like then? youre saying for the next 2, but what if the person enters in a 9? i know a comparison is not being made correctly here:



 if (HoursWorked >= 8 && HoursWorked <= 10)
cout << "For the hours you worked over 8, and less than or equal to 10 you made: " << HoursWorked * 1.5 * WagePerHour << " \n";
else (HoursWorked >10);
cout << "For the hours you worked over 10: " << HoursWorked * 2.0 * WagePerHour << " \n";

Comment: Hint: `int hoursBetween = HoursWorked - 8;`

Comment: For each part, you need to work out how many hours to pay. The first part is going to be a number between 0 and 8. You need to make sure it isn't more than 8. For the second part (time and a half) you need a number between 0 and 2. Add the pay for these two hours to the amount for the first 8. For the final part.... what's the maximum? Perhaps beyond the scope of the question. Anyway, however many hours they worked above 10, pay them double rate for those hours.

Comment: I think you want _nested_ `if` statements

Comment: is there a way to set a value to TimeandHalf and Overtime?

i want to make it so that on my line where it says
if (HoursWorked >= 8 && HoursWorked <= 10)
cout << "Your pay for 8-10 hours worked is: " << HoursWorked * 1.5 * WagePerHour << " before Uncle Sam takes his cut \n";
i want to set that equal to TimeandHalf..is this possible or am i making this complicated for myself?

Comment: @TimRandall

i am in a very begining c++ class and dont really know a whole lot about nested if statements and whatnot.

   if (HoursWorked >= 8 && HoursWorked <= 10)
cout << "Your pay for 8-10 hours worked is: " << HoursWorked * 1.5 * WagePerHour << " before Uncle Sam takes his cut \n";
if (HoursWorked >10);
cout << "Your pay for hours 10 and beyond: " << HoursWorked * 2.0 * WagePerHour << " before Uncle Sam takes his cut \n";
else
cout << "Your Total is" HoursWorked + WagePerHour + TimeAndHalf + DoubleTime << "before uncle sam"

Comment: i somewhat figured out how to set a value to TimeandHalf and Doubletime
int main()
{
TimeAndHalf = HoursWorked * WagePerHour * 1.5;
DoubleTime = HoursWorked * WagePerHour * 2.0;


but if (HoursWorked >10);
cout << "Your pay for hours 10 and beyond: " << HoursWorked * 2.0 * WagePerHour << " before Uncle Sam takes his cut \n";
else
cout << "Your Total is" HoursWorked + WagePerHour + TimeAndHalf + DoubleTime <<

doesnt compute correctly. there is a incorrect comparison being made somewhere

Comment: The problem is you are calculating too many hours for TimeAndHalf  and DoubleTime. You don't use HoursWorked because that is the total number of hours. This is more of a math problem than a programming one.

Comment: the prompt:Write a program to input a wage in hours and to input the hours worked in a day.
Please use appropriate data types for your variables.
Put your paycheck code inside a while loop that asks if the user after computing one paycheck gross pay wants to compute again. ( Y=Yes), etc.
After 8 hours any hours worked will be paid time and a half. That is, given the wage per hour multiply by 1.5. That wage is paid for hours after 8 hours.
After 10 hours any hours worked will be paid double time. That is, given the wage per hour multiply by 2.0. That wage is paid for hours after 10 hours.

Comment: Please show: ( Example output )
Wage per hour: 12.37
Hours worked : 10.3 
Pay for ( 0 to 8 hours) :98.96
Pay for hours 8 to 10) :37.11
Pay for hours (10 and beyond): 7.42
Total Gross Pay :143.49

Comment: @drescherjm see above

Comment: okay everyone, i got my code to work, however...my math is incorrect...@drescherjm  @timrandall

Comment: if (HoursWorked <=8){
    PayFirstEight = HoursWorked * WagePerHour;
    PayEightToTen = 0.0;
    PayGreaterTen = 0.0;
    cout << "Your pay for first 8 hours worked is: " << PayFirstEight << " \n";
}if (HoursWorked >= 8 && HoursWorked <= 10){
    PayFirstEight = HoursWorked * WagePerHour;
    PayEightToTen = HoursWorked * 1.5 * WagePerHour;
    PayGreaterTen = 0.0;
    cout << "Your pay for hours 8-10: " << PayEightToTen << " before Uncle Sam takes his cut \n";
}

Comment: if (HoursWorked >10){
    PayFirstEight = HoursWorked * WagePerHour;
    PayEightToTen = HoursWorked * 1.5 * WagePerHour;
    PayGreaterTen = HoursWorked * 2.0 * WagePerHour;
    cout << "Your pay for above 10 hours is: " << PayGreaterTen << " before Uncle Sam takes his cut \n";
};

TotalWages = PayFirstEight + PayEightToTen + PayGreaterTen;
cout << "Your Total is: " << TotalWages << " before Uncle Sam takes his cut \n";

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this. Here is one. The comments may help you to follow my reasoning. Fortunately the mathematics behind this is not very complicated.

```
/*
We need to find the area under this pay rate / hours worked graph.
The following approach divides the graph into three rectangles as shown below
2.0 |         +--+
    |         |  |
1.5 |       +-+--|
    |       |    |
1.0 +-------+----|
    |            |
0.5 |            |
    |            |
0.0 +------------+
    0       8 10
*/
// Calculate basic pay before any overtime consideration
Pay = HoursWorked * HourlyRate;

// Hours above 8 earn half-again more than the standard wage.
// (This will be only positive if more than 8 hours were worked.)
OvertimePay = (HoursWorked - 8.0) * HourlyRate * 0.5;
if(OvertimePay > 0.0)
    Pay += OvertimePay;

// Hours above 10 earn an additional 50% extra
// (This will be only positive if more than 10 hours were worked.)
OvertimePay = (HoursWorked - 10.0) * HourlyRate * 0.5;
if(OvertimePay > 0.0)
    Pay += OvertimePay;
```